# Token gate a link

Tags: wallets, nft

I am starting out with Tezos and I am wanting to give holders of my Tezos NFTs access to additional files which are unique to each NFT. So the holder of NFT_A will have access to file a.mp4 and holder of NFT_B will have access to b.mp4.

I have been able to connect to a wallet using Tequito but I am unsure how to proceed. Has anyone got any idea how I can achieve this? Mintgate offers this as a service but I would like to try and get it working myself. They refer to it as "token gated links".

Answer (score 0):

You will have to include those files in the token metadata.

The specification can be found [here](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tzip/-/blob/master/proposals/tzip-21/tzip-21.md).

[Metadata example](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tzip/-/blob/master/proposals/tzip-21/examples/example-020-digital-collectible.json)

Comment: Thanks for that, however, the files would contain the "gated" content so I have gone down a different route. Thanks for the answer though.